# iOS 8 CLLocationManagerDelegate methods are never called

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

> //View did Load Method- LocationManager is allocated and have included the CLLocationManagerDelegate in .h File
>
> ```
> -ViewDidLoad{
> self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
>     self.locationManager.delegate = self;
>     self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
>     self.locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
>     [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
>     [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
>     [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
>
> }
> // Location Manager Delegate Methods
> - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
> {
>     NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you `NSLog` the results of `[self.locationManager authorizationStatus]` and `[self.locationManager locationServicesEnabled]`?

Comment: Also, don't know if it's a typo, but eventually replace `-ViewDidLoad{` with: `- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; ...`

Comment: Did you see the authorization dialog? Did you specify the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` message in the plist?

Comment: It is not calling the delegate method.

Comment: Did not see authorization dialog, but have added the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in plist.

Comment: [self.locationManager locationServicesEnabled];
YES
Not able to call [self.locationManager authorizationStatus] gives me error: No Visible @interface for CLLocationManager declares the selector authorizationStatus

Comment: Can anyone provide me with an example which works both for iOS 7 and iOS 8 for Locations with authorization dialog and if user agrees it should be enabled in "Settings"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In plist you have to add 2 entries

1. NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
2. NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Make the string of both as "Location is required to find out where you are" or anything

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
CLAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus= [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

if (authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    NSLog(@"You are authorized");

}

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In plist you have to add 2 entries

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription  if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; This worked for me. Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: @Laxy If it works please accept this as an answer please