# screen not zoom to right coordinates - swift google map api

Tags: swift, google-maps, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios

when getting dynamic google map with using GMSMap the map doesn't show the current location that i gave him and not zoom the map

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import MapKit

class LocationItemViewController: UIViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lblInfo: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()     
    let latitude = (String(format:"%.02f", locationItem.itemLatitude ) as NSString).doubleValue
    let longgitude = (String(format:"%.02f", locationItem.itemLongitude) as NSString).doubleValue
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(latitude,longitude: longgitude, zoom: 7)

    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.googleMapView = mapView
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((locationItem.itemLatitude as NSString).doubleValue, (locationItem.itemLongitude as NSString).doubleValue)
    marker.title = "somelocation"
    marker.snippet = "anywhere"
    marker.map = mapView
    lblTitle.text = locationItem.itemName
    lblInfo.text = locationItem.itemAddress
}
```

I was locate the GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY") in app delegate

Comment: this is because you are not animating the camera

Comment: Check my posted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display your current location you have to do the same thing which we do for apple maps to access our location.

In plist you have to add 2 entries and take permission from User

1. **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
2. **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

Check this link for more details
 [iOS 8 CLLocationManagerDelegate methods are never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837146/ios-8-cllocationmanagerdelegate-methods-are-never-called)

Now regarding your google maps zoom issue

```
var mapView:GMSMapView?
```

Now in your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")

    //Taking HardCoded lat longs for the time being. These lat longs are of New Delhi, India
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(28.6139, longitude: 77.2090, zoom: 10)
    mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView!.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.6139, 77.2090)
    marker.title = "Delhi"
    marker.snippet = "India"
    marker.map = mapView

    //As view takes some time to load so I am calling my zoom function after a delay of 1 second. You can use the zoom function code in viewDidAppear too
    //Also this syntax is the latest Swift 2.2 syntax. If you are using the old Swift version, make the changes accordingly for performSelector method
    self.performSelector(#selector(zoom), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)

}
```

Here is the zoom method

```
func zoom() {

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(1, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)

    // It will animate your camera to the specified lat and long
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(28.6139, longitude: 77.2090, zoom: 15)
    mapView!.animateToCameraPosition(camera)

    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: still not working can you present me full code because its seems that i missing something

Comment: you just copy my code and re run for the time being comment your full code.

Comment: just add to your answer       viewMap.addSubview(self.googleMap!)
and your answer is current

Comment: @shaharnakash I have already written `self.view = mapView` as I am making my complete view as the mapView.